D-Link DWA 131 (8192eu) on an old system
I have tried getting this to work for 3 weeks now with no luck. I finally found drivers that would actually compile (DWA-131_Linux_v4.3.1.1 unpacking into 20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320)
uname -a
Linux zuul 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

after a make, make install, reboot and inserting the usb dmesg says:
CPU: 0 PID: 4142 Comm: modprobe Tainted: G           O    4.1.7-v7+ #817
[  352.470250] Hardware name: BCM2709
[  352.471695] task: b802f200 ti: b82b0000 task.ti: b82b0000
[  352.473203] PC is at load_module+0x1a60/0x1f30
[  352.474724] LR is at load_module+0x1a4c/0x1f30
[  352.476240] pc : [<800979dc>]    lr : [<800979c8>]    psr: 90000013
[  352.476240] sp : b82b1e88  ip : 7f1d83c4  fp : b82b1f3c
[  352.479402] r10: 7f1d824c  r9 : 80564800  r8 : b92d9ae0
[  352.481045] r7 : 7f1d8294  r6 : 7f1d8258  r5 : fe37a4e4  r4 : b82b1f40
[  352.482745] r3 : 00000001  r2 : b82b1e70  r1 : b3709500  r0 : 8080a750
[  352.484493] Flags: NzcV  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[  352.486310] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 3341806a  DAC: 00000015
[  352.488171] Process modprobe (pid: 4142, stack limit = 0xb82b0210)
[  352.490091] Stack: (0xb82b1e88 to 0xb82b2000)
[  352.492054] 1e80:                   7f1d8258 00007fff 800947b8 b82b1edc 00000000 00000003
[  352.494135] 1ea0: b82b1f74 b82b1f48 000015c5 be0c3068 7f1d8258 7f1ddfac 7f1baf54 7f1d83c4
[  352.496278] 1ec0: b82b0000 b3544000 76d70000 808eafe4 00004a3e 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  352.498488] 1ee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  352.500706] 1f00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 be118000 00008a3e 00000000 76d74a3e
[  352.502926] 1f20: be120a3e b82b0000 76fa8948 00000000 b82b1fa4 b82b1f40 80097f88 80095f88
[  352.505204] 1f40: be008000 00118a3e be0c2aa0 be0c2920 be1125b0 000bcfac 000c8bac 00000000
[  352.507542] 1f60: 00000000 00000000 00000025 00000026 0000001a 0000001e 0000000e 00000000
[  352.509918] 1f80: 00000000 00060000 54e4d670 00000080 8000fb88 b82b0000 00000000 b82b1fa8
[  352.512325] 1fa0: 8000f980 80097eb8 00000000 00060000 76c5c000 00118a3e 76fa8948 76c5c000
[  352.514783] 1fc0: 00000000 00060000 54e4d670 00000080 54e4ccf0 00118a3e 76fa8948 00000000
[  352.517271] 1fe0: 00000000 7ec0b8fc 76f9ffb4 76f0ae94 60000010 76c5c000 00000000 00000000
[  352.519813] [<800979dc>] (load_module) from [<80097f88>] (SyS_init_module+0xdc/0x134)
[  352.522417] [<80097f88>] (SyS_init_module) from [<8000f980>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x54)
[  352.525078] Code: e51bc080 e15c0005 e2455008 0a000009 (e5953014)
[  352.527781] ---[ end trace 8ed1858ffe3971b2 ]---

I now also tried lordy2y's fork of manges repository, when inserting USB:
Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.579787] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.601932] Process modprobe (pid: 2816, stack limit = 0xb6c1c210)

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.603854] Stack: (0xb6c1de88 to 0xb6c1e000)

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.605814] de80:                   7f212bec 00007fff 800947b8 b6c1dedc 00000000 00000003

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.607894] dea0: b6c1df74 b6c1df48 0000192f be00317c 7f212bec 7f2192a4 7f1e515c 7f212d58

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.610038] dec0: b6c1c000 b9317000 76d62000 808eafe4 0000930a 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.612245] dee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.614467] df00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 be072000 0000930a 00000000 76d6b30a

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.616694] df20: be07b30a b6c1c000 76fa0948 00000000 b6c1dfa4 b6c1df40 80097f88 80095f88

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.618984] df40: bdf12000 0016930a be002a74 be00288c be065624 000f12a4 001038f4 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.621328] df60: 00000000 00000000 0000002d 0000002e 00000022 00000026 00000016 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.623717] df80: 00000000 00060000 55c03670 00000080 8000fb88 b6c1c000 00000000 b6c1dfa8

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.626138] dfa0: 8000f980 80097eb8 00000000 00060000 76c02000 0016930a 76fa0948 76c02000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.628604] dfc0: 00000000 00060000 55c03670 00000080 55c02d58 0016930a 76fa0948 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.631103] dfe0: 00000000 7e8c78fc 76f97fb4 76f02e94 60000010 76c02000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@zuul at Dec 19 15:25:14 ...
 kernel:[  153.638949] Code: e51bc080 e15c0005 e2455008 0a000009 (e5953014)


https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069137/d-link-dwa-131-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-04

This old release don't have drivers for the dongle built in and no blacklisting of it.

Are you using a Raspberry Pi or some other hardware? What is the operating system?

Raspberry pi Debian 4.1.7-v7+ #817

Raspberry Pi Drivers for the rtl8192eu chipset for wireless adapters (D-Link DWA-131 rev E1 included!) (https://github.com/lord2y/rtl8192eu-arm-linux-driver)

Yes I tried those drivers before, also the one it's forked from. Throws pretty much the same error as the one above.

v1.0 - This is a stable version of the driver tested with Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi Zero. You can download pre build .deb package for raspbian kernel version 4.4.38+ and 4.4.38-v7+  (https://github.com/lord2y/rtl8192eu-arm-linux-driver/releases) (1) It provides .deb download (2) It provides the hardware it has verified: Pi 3, Pi Zero. (3) It states that its OS environment is raspbian kernel version 4.4.38+ and 4.4.38-v7+ (4) So you can consider using the raspbian environment.

That's where I'm stuck since every time I try to bump up the kernal and upgrade it breaks scripts on the server. Those scripts are not made by me so I cannot handle them.

What I mean is (1) your hardware is Pi 3 or just Pi 1? (2) your OS is using Debian 4.1.7-v7+ #817, have you considered using raspbian? Test again?

It's a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1. I cannot change os as there is alot of stuff on the server that breaks even if I upgrade the existing version
